# Подскажите, нужно ли обособлять "скорее" в вопросе?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

"Поступил ли он правильно? Или все-таки его поступок — это скорее ошибка неверного выбора?"

Answer (score 4):

Выделять запятыми слово "скорее" не нужно.

[**СКОРЕЕ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_671)

> Слово «скорее» не требует постановки знаков препинания, если в предложении подразумевается сопоставление «скорее… чем», «скорее… нежели».

*Посетители походили **скорее** на бизнесменов. Всё это напоминало **скорее** глупую комедию.* (Ср.: *Посетители походили **скорее** на бизнесменов, **чем** на любопытных зевак; Всё это напоминало **скорее** глупую комедию, **нежели** реальное происшествие).*

*Поступил ли он правильно? Или все-таки его поступок — это **скорее** ошибка неверного выбора [, **чем** намеренное решение]?"*

Answer (score 3):

*Поступил ли он правильно? Или все-таки его поступок — это **скорее** ошибка неверного выбора.*

Слово "скорее" не обособляется, так как здесь подразумевается  сопоставление «скорее… чем», «скорее… нежели», а значение вводности (скорее говоря) отсутствует.

Вообще говоря, "скорее" редко обособляется, так как  необособление допускается даже при наличии вводного значения, обособление же этого слова является  довольно распространенной ошибкой.